# Will upgrading 13.10 to 14.04 affect my full-disk encryption?

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, encryption

Will upgrading 13.10 to 14.04 affect my full-disk encryption?

I just recently installed 64-bit 13.10 with full disk encryption. Will the next LTS release in April affect and/or clash with my encrypted setup?