# Upgrading from 14.04 LTS to the next LTS with FDE

Tags: 14.04, encryption, lts

Since 14.04.06 dropped out of Standard Support end of April, I am looking to upgrade my installation to the next sensible LTS version. The updater recommends upgrading to 16.04.06 LTS.

Obviously I will do a full backup of my data just in case.

Additionally, since I am running with full disk encryption (I see a reference to sda5_crypt during the encryptionkey prompt during bootup), I am looking for more information, if that FDE setup will survive the upgrade to another LTS.

```
$ df
udev             3922128         4   3922124    1% /dev
tmpfs             787712      1612    786100    1% /run
/dev/dm-1      237808280 221330156   4375060   99% /
none                   4         0         4    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120         0      5120    0% /run/lock
none             3938544    183456   3755088    5% /run/shm
none              102400        60    102340    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1         240972    129354     99177   57% /boot
```

Comment: FDE should pose no problem when upgrading. I have upgraded my system over the years from 14.04 until 19.04 (though not from LTS to LTS) and never encountered any problem with disk encryption (my setup includes an encrypted LVM).

Comment: Thanks. How can I check if I also have an encrypted LVM?

Comment: Edit your question to post the outcome of `df` If you see something like `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` you are using LVM. Though even without LVM, the Full disk encryption should not be a problem. Having said that, an upgrade always has some residual risks, which is why the full backup is a good idea.

Comment: You do not seem to have setup LVM, but a fulldisk encryption with LUKS. Nonetheless, this should pose no problem on upgrading.

Comment: Thank you. Do you suggest closing the question in this case?

Comment: No need to close. You could come back here and answer your own question if all goes well. There have been similar questions in the past, but without getting an answer as e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/410826/will-upgrading-13-10-to-14-04-affect-my-full-disk-encryption So an answer might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommendes as per above: the upgrade regarding the encryption wenth through fine.

Note to anyone else: If you have external PPAs activce which might interfere with your installation, it's best do downgrade your system withouth those PPAs active or your upgrade might fail.